# Nested tag name with getElementsByTagName doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, sorting

I have the following div that contains the table and its data queried from database

```
<div id="content">
<table>
<tbody>
   <tr>
       <th class="header" colspan="2">Food items include:</th>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td id="15" class="fruits">Papaya+salt</td>
      <td><p>This includes papaya and salt</p></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td class="meat">Baked chicken</td>
      <td><p>This includes a chicken thide and kethup</p></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td id="1" class="Juices">Strawberry Sting</td>
      <td><p>Sugar, color and water</p></td>
   </tr>
<table>
</div>
```

That table is defined in a page.aspx

and here is my code used to sort that table data alphabetically

```
OldFunc = window.onload;
window.onload = OnLoad;

function OnLoad(){
    try{
        var pathName = window.location.pathname.toLowerCase();
        if( pathName=="/Resources/Glossary.aspx") {
                sort_it();
            }   
        OldFunc();
    }
    catch(e) {
    }
} 

function TermDefinition(def_term,def_desc)
{    
    this.def_term=def_term;  
    this.def_desc=def_desc; 
}    

function sort_it()
{
    var gloss_list=document.getElementsByTagName('td');    
    var desc_list=document.getElementsByTagName('td p');    
    var gloss_defs=[];   
    var list_length=gloss_list.length;     
    for(var i=0;i<list_length;i++)    
    {      
       gloss_defs[i]=new TermDefinition(gloss_list[i].firstChild.nodeValue,desc_list[i].firstChild.nodeValue);      
    }     
    gloss_defs.sort(function(a, b){
      var termA=a.def_term.toLocaleUpperCase(); 
      var termB=b.def_term.toLocaleUpperCase();
      if (termA < termB) 
       return -1;
      if (termA > termB)
       return 1;
      return 0; 
    })    
    for(var i=0;i<gloss_defs.length;i++)
    {
       gloss_list[i].firstChild.nodeValue=gloss_defs[i].def_term;
       desc_list[i].firstChild.nodeValue=gloss_defs[i].def_desc;  
    }
}
```

Please lookat the the two getElementsByTagName, I think I am misuse its content since nothing is done on the output.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Invalid**:

```
desc_list=document.getElementsByTagName('td p');
```

You can't pass a css selector to that function, only a tag name like `div`\ `span` `input` etc'.

You might want to use:

```
desc_list = $('td p');
```

Since you tagged the question with jQuery, or `document.querySelectorAll` for vanilla js:

```
desc_list = document.querySelectorAll('td p');
```